# Regex, поиск всех совпадений

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется исходная строка

> текст текст текст >>Название ссылки>>https://example.com>> и текст текст текст 
>    текст >>ссылка 2>>https://2example.com>>.

Пробую следующую конструкцию `\>>(.*)>>(.*)>>\s\`находится только одно совпадение.
Подскажите, что нужно сделать для того, чтобы выбирались все совпадения.

Пример:
https://regex101.com/r/DH8jHe/2

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: у вас под выражение попадает только одно совпадение, которое оно вам и выдает. а второе не подходит, потому что после ссылки там стоит точка а не пробел который вы указали в выражении

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
preg_match_all('~>>(.*?)>>(.*?)>>~u', $s, $matches);
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/sOz46o/1).

Если вдруг на одной строке будет несколько совпадений, использование ленивого квантификатора позволит получить их все, а не соединит эти совпадения в одно. Модификатор `u` надо использовать при работе со строками Юникода.

См. PHP-демо:

```
$s = "текст текст текст >>Название ссылки>>https://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com>> и текст текст текст текст >>ссылка 2>>https://2...content-available-to-author-only...e.com>>.";
preg_match_all('~>>(.*?)>>(.*?)>>~u', $s, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => >>Название ссылки>>https://example.com>>
            [1] => >>ссылка 2>>https://2example.com>>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Название ссылки
            [1] => ссылка 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://example.com
            [1] => https://2example.com
        )

)
```

Comment: Премного благодарен всем за ответы!

Answer (score 1):

`\s` в конце вашего выражения означает "любой пробельный символ". 
Ваш пример заканчивается точкой, а не пробелом, и, по этому, вторая ссылка не подходит. При этом, после первой ссылки пробел есть, она и определяется правильно.
Об этом уже верно написал @Mike.